# why getting unexpected identifier error? Im obviously noob

Tags: javascript

```
function myFavFood(food){
    var msg = "";
    if(food === "pizza")
    msg = "I love " + food;
    if (food === "hotpockets")
    msg = food + " woo";
    if (food !== "pizza" && food!== "hotpockets")
    msg = "I have bad taste in foods";
    return 'msg'

}
var pizza = myFavFood("pizza")
var hot pockets = myFavFood("hotpockets")
var not hot pizza = myFavFood();

console.log(pizza, hot pockets, anything)
```

Comment: Try a ; after `return 'msg'`

Comment: Also in your console.log(), you should take out "anything" or define it. Otherwise that will be an error also when your code actually runs.

Comment: I suggest to follow a JavaScript tutorial. E.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: @ParrisVarney: Semicolons are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use spaces between variables, for instance:

```
// INVALID variable name
var hot pockets = "something";

// VALID variable names
var hotPockets = "something";
var hot_pockets = "something";
```

You can find more information and examples [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Variables cannot have spaces... Eliminate those and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the the spaces between your variables such as `var hot pockets` to `var hotPockets` and `var not hot pizza` to `var notHotPizza` will get ride of the unexpected identifier error.

```
var pizza = myFavFood("pizza")
var hotPockets = myFavFood("hotpockets")
var notHotPizza = myFavFood();

console.log(pizza, hotPockets, notHotPizza);
```

Also, remove the single quotes around `return 'msg'` to `return msg` to return the message and not the string `"msg"`.

```
return msg;
```